# Перехват ответа с бекэнда в saga

Tags: reactjs, redux-saga

При изучении react'a натолкнулся на непонятную мне проблему.
Я не понимаю почему в response нету ид, хотя я возвращаю в контроллере. Сам response undefined.

id поста создается на бэкенде и я хочу получать ид созданного поста

Можете подсказать где я ошибся?

**Java:**

Service:

```
public UUID savePost(CreatePostDto createPostDto) {
        var post = PostMapper.MAPPER.createPostDtoToPost(createPostDto);
        var tags = new HashSet<>(tagRepository.findAllById(createPostDto.getTags()));
        post.setTags(tags);
        var savedPost = postRepository.save(post);
        elasticService.put(savedPost);
        return savedPost.getId();
    }
```

Controller:

```
@PostMapping("/create")
    public UUID createPost(@RequestBody CreatePostDto post) {
        return postService.savePost(post);
    }
```

**JavaScript:**

Send Post:

```
function* sendPost(action) {
  try {
    const response = yield call(createPostService.sendPost, action.payload);
    yield put(sendPostRoutine.success(response));
    toastr.success('Success', 'Post was sent!');
    history.push(`/post/${response.id}`);
  } catch (error) {
    yield put(sendImageRoutine.failure(error?.message));
    toastr.error('Error', 'Sending post failed!');
  }
}
```

Send post service:

```
 sendPost: async (post: object) => { await api.post('/api/post/create', { data: post }); },
```

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался

service на фронте выглядит теперь так:

```
const sendPostFetch = async (post: object) => api.post('/api/post/create', { data: post });

sendPost: async (post: object) => sendPostFetch(post),
```